Data transformation on pandas dataframe to connect related rows based on shared values

I have a table of company data that links subsidiary to parent companies as shown in the left hand side table of the screenshot. I need to transform the data into the table on the right hand side of the screenshot. This requires tracing through the two columns of the table and making the link between individual rows.
So far the only thing I have tried is to join the table against itself recursively.. but I am thinking that some kind of tree structure here would make more sense? I.e. creating a branch of all connected companies with the 'ultimate parent company' as the trunk?
These concepts are new to me so appreciate any input
Reproducible input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subsidiary Company': ['Company B', 'Company C', 'Company D', 'Company 2', 'Company 3'],
                   'Parent Company': ['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C', 'Company 1', 'Company 2']})


In addition to your images please provide a [mre] as code/text.

What have you tried? show us code.

You can use networkx to form a directed graph, then loop over the paths with all_simple_paths:
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

# create the directed graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Subsidiary Company',
                            target='Parent Company',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find roots (final level companies)
roots = {v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0}
# {'Company 3', 'Company D'}

# find leaves (ultimate parents)
leaves = {v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0}
# {'Company 1', 'Company A'}

# function to rename the columns
# 0 is the subsidiary company
# inf is the ultimate parent
# other numbers are intermediates
def renamer(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 'Subsidiary Company'
    if np.isfinite(x):
        return f'Intermediate Parent Company {int(x)}'
    return 'Ultimate Parent Company'

# find the connected nodes
# the roots/leaves for each group
# iterate over the paths between each root/node combination
# create the sliding paths (with range) 
# convert to DataFrame
out = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        [
            dict(enumerate(p[i-1:-1])) | {float('inf'): p[-1]}
            for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G)
            for r in c & roots
            for l in c & leaves
            for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, r, l)
            for i in range(len(p)-1, 0, -1)
        ]
    )
    .sort_index(axis=1)
    .rename(columns=renamer)
)

Output:
  Subsidiary Company Intermediate Parent Company 1 Intermediate Parent Company 2 Ultimate Parent Company
0          Company B                           NaN                           NaN               Company A
1          Company C                     Company B                           NaN               Company A
2          Company D                     Company C                     Company B               Company A
3          Company 2                           NaN                           NaN               Company 1
4          Company 3                     Company 2                           NaN               Company 1


This worked perfectly for me!!! Thank you. I am working my way through the networkx documentation to get a full understanding of what is happening here - if you happen to have time and could add some explanatory comments in that would be a huge help. Cheers!

@AW_ I commented the code to describe the steps. If you want to understand the nested loop, you can convert the list comprehension to a classical nested for loop.

A graph structure can do what you need.  Add the nodes as a mapping to the parent company and then build the relationship chains.  Here is an example of the data similar to you image.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Subsidiary': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', '2', '3'],
    'Parent': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', '1', '2']
})

Below is the data structure to handle building parentage chains as well as reformatting the data to a wide data frame.
class SubsidiaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.node_to_parent = {}

    def add_edge(self, subsidiary, parent):
        self.node_to_parent[subsidiary] = parent
        self.node_to_parent.setdefault(parent, None)

    def build_decendents(self):
        chains = []
        for sub, parent in self.node_to_parent.items():
            if parent is None:
                continue
            chain = [sub, parent]
            while parent is not None:
                parent = self.node_to_parent[parent]
                if parent is not None:
                    chain.append(parent)
            chains.append(chain)
        return chains
    
    def build_wide_df(self):
        data = []
        for i, chain in enumerate(self.build_decendents()):
            first = chain.pop(0)
            last = chain.pop()
            data.append([i, 'subsidiary', first])
            data.extend([[i, f'intermidiate-{j}', x] for j, x in enumerate(chain, 1)])
            data.append([i, 'parent', last])
        df_long = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ix', 'relation', 'company'])
        p = df_long.pivot(columns='relation', index='ix', values='company').fillna('')
        cols = set(p.columns).difference(['parent', 'subsidiary'])
        return p[['subsidiary', *sorted(cols), 'parent']]

To use the tree structure:
st = SubsidiaryTree()
for _, (s, p) in df.iterrows():
    st.add_edge(s, p)

st.build_wide_df()
# returns:
relation subsidiary intermidiate-1 intermidiate-2 parent
ix
0                 B                                    A
1                 C              B                     A
2                 D              C              B      A
3                 E              B                     A
4                 2                                    1
5                 3              2                     1


When working with tabular data, moving one step along a hierarchy is a join
operation. You can start with all of your leaves and work your way up the hierarchy
until you can no longer any parent data. Then you can take each of those links
you created and concatenate them together.
At the end of this we need to massage the resultant data since the connections
are are all left-aligned to the table. This is done via a forward fill and mask
operation to appropriately put the ultimate parent and leaf subsidiary nodes at
either end of the table with the intermediate steps in the middle.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Subsidiary': ['B', 'C', 'D', '2', '3'],
    'Parent':     ['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '2']
})

links = [df['Subsidiary']]
while True:
    link = (
        links[-1].to_frame().merge(df, on='Subsidiary', how='left')['Parent']
    )
    if link.isna().all(): # no more data to merge on
        break
    links.append(link.rename('Subsidiary'))

new_columns = [
    'Subsidiary',
    *(f'Interpediate {i}' for i in range(len(links)-2)),
    'Parent'
]

results = (
    pd.concat(links, keys=new_columns, axis=1)
    .ffill(axis=1)
    .mask(lambda d: d.shift(-1, axis=1).eq(d))
)

print(results)
#   Subsidiary Interpediate 0 Interpediate 1 Parent
# 0          B            NaN            NaN      A
# 1          C              B            NaN      A
# 2          D              C              B      A
# 3          2            NaN            NaN      1
# 4          3              2            NaN      1

